# Replace null values with the most recent value in a time series

Tags: powerquery

I have this series (notice the holes in the dates):

| Date | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 2019-12-31 | 100 |
| 2020-01-02 | 110 |
| 2020-01-05 | 120 |
| 2020-01-07 | 125 |
| 2020-01-08 | 130 |

And I need to get this one:

| Date | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 2019-12-31 | 100 |
| **2020-01-01** | **100** |
| 2020-01-02 | 110 |
| **2020-01-03** | **110** |
| **2020-01-04** | **110** |
| 2020-01-05 | 120 |
| **2020-01-06** | **120** |
| 2020-01-07 | 125 |
| 2020-01-08 | 130 |

Notice that the rows with bold font didn't exist in the first table and the values are *forward filled* from the most recent value available.

To get this done:

1. I created a dummy calendar with the `List.Dates()` function.
2. I merged this calendar with the first table obtaining this:

| Date | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 2019-12-31 | 100 |
| **2020-01-01** | ***null*** |
| 2020-01-02 | 110 |
| **2020-01-03** | ***null*** |
| **2020-01-04** | ***null*** |
| 2020-01-05 | 120 |
| **2020-01-06** | ***null*** |
| 2020-01-07 | 125 |
| 2020-01-08 | 130 |

3. Then I created a function that took a date as a parameter which filtered the first table and with the function `List.Last()` took the last non-null value and placed it in the row of the third table instead of the null.

It works quite well, but I find it too slow. For each row the function must be called to scan the table for the most recent value available.

Is there a quicker way to perform this?

Comment: [Fill down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64540697/powerquery-fill-missing-data-according-to-specific-pattern)

Comment: @AlexisOlson I can't believe it is that simple. Thank you!!!